# How to hide specific file path from source code (wp-admin/admin-ajax.php)?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have this in my source code:

```
 <script>... "ajaxurl":"https:\/\/example.com\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php"...</script>
```

Is it possible to hide the `wp-admin` & the `admin-ajax.php` through htaccess or something?

It seems the above code is generated from a plugin and I think it's a security risk.

Comment: If the knowledge of a path is an actual security risk then your site shouldn't be online in the first place.

Comment: I don't think it is a security risk because you can't get codes from a php file through AJAX requests.

Comment: It's a security risk because you're advertising to the world you're using wordpress. There are very nice plugins which hide `wp-content` and `wp-includes` from the source code to hide your wordpress installation, but seems some plugins bypass it and show the `wp-admin` within the source code.

Answer (score 0):

I understand the pain behind the open admin URL, so what I've done is replaced the wp-admin to something else, find it in below URL.

https://managewp.com/blog/change-your-wordpress-login-url

Though few warnings(directly from the link TL;DR):

- Compatibility might be an issue. Make sure to read and understand all
  the Better WP Security options before changing any settings. Talk to
  your web host or developer before continuing if you know you have an
  unusual setup but aren’t sure how it may be affected by this plugin.
  I tested with WP Engine and didn’t have any issues. Follow the plugin
  author’s recommendation and read the Better WP Security Installation
  Tips and FAQs.
- If you already have the site added to ManageWP Dashboard, you’ll need
  to update your ManageWP options, but it’s quick and easy. Also,
  please read the ManageWP “Known Issues”, which mentions one of
  features of the Better WP Security plugin.
- Continue reading for all the step-by-step instructions for Better WP
  Security and updating the ManageWP Dashboard options.

Comment: I actually use that plugin, the problem is it seems it doesn't hide `wp-admin` within the source code. It does hide `wp-content` and `wp-includes` though.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Wordpress plugin WPS Hide Login. Once its installed an activated, in the general settings you set a new path (pick something random eg. RaNdOm639) to your login. eg. yourwebsite.com/RaNdOm639, while going to yourwebsite.com/wp-admin will result in a 404 error
Good Luck
GRI2A